# Force upgrade 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed and until a few weeks back it used to remind me to do an upgrade to 13.04 but at that time I was not interested.
Now that I want to upgrade I don't know how to do that.I tried update manager in the dashboard but it says all software is updated.

How do I force the upgrade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

Once that is done, a window will open, just click on Upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, and type the following:

```
update-manager -d
```