# How to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.10 without official update for 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I can't update the version to 13.10 because it doesn't automatically show up, telling me to update in the Software Centre. There is no official update from Ubuntu for 13.10.

Comment: If you're on 12.10, you'll first have to upgrade to 13.04, then to 13.10. If the Software Center is not showing you any upgrades, see the answer to this question: [Force upgrade 12.10 to 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/299198/52726).

Comment: You cannot upgrade your distribution from 12.10 directly to 13.10 but you have to upgrade it to 13.04 before upgrading it to 13.10. The Software Centre does not show the updates. Firstly, open Terminal and enter `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are to either update to 13.04, then update to 13.10. Or, more preferably, reinstall Ubuntu with a 13.10 CD. Make sure to back up all your data first. If you plan on skipping versions when upgrading often, it's a good idea to have a separate home partition on your hard drive to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+alt+t to open the console and after this put in the console the next:
update-manager -d.
This will show you something about updating your software so put yes or ok and after this it will say something like:  " your version of ubuntu is 12.04 but it´s exist a 12.10 ubuntu version. if you want update it, just follow the instructions and done. (Its a long process so be patient)
Hope this information will help you.